# Refactoring Actions are Disabled - Python Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: resharper, ptvs

When trying to, e.g., rename variables, the actions within the refactor context menu are disabled. Keybinds for these actions are also disabled.
I tried this with PTVS 2.0 and 2.1 beta in Visual Studio 2013.

I do also have ReSharper installed, but I would hope that doesn't interfere with PTVS.

Anyone have a guess about what causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper is to blame.

Disabling ReSharper via `Tools > Options > ReSharper` restores the ability to refactor Python code.

---

**Edit:** Another option is to go to `ReSharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus`

Untick `Hide overridden Visual Studio menu items`
This restores the built-in refactor menu and also allows using refactor keybinds.